# Equivalent to ajaxSend and/or ajaxComplete with jsonp?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

Right now I use:

```
$("#status")
    .on("ajaxSend", function() { $(this).show(); } )
    .on("ajaxComplete", function() { $(this).hide(); } );
```

To get a status when ajax was working.  This worked with json, but not with jsonp.  Is there a way to get this to work with jsonp?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to [be a bug in jQuery](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajaxsend-not-fired-with-jsonp), or at least consideration for a bug.

Unfortunately you can't do anything about it at this point except update your jsonp requests to use the same things on `beforeSend` and `complete`:

```
function ajaxSend() { $("#status").show(); }
function ajaxComplete() { $("#status").hide(); }

$.ajaxSend(ajaxSend);
$.ajax({
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   beforeSend: ajaxSend,
   complete: ajaxComplete
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Being a relative newbie to jQuery & ajax I'm not sure if this answers your question, but I've found that event handlers inside `ajaxSetup()` will automatically be called for jsonp requests, whereas standalone handlers such as `$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqXHR, settings){});` will not. And as Explosion Pills said, you can also manually override these on a per-call basis.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
    },
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    }
});
```