# AJAX jsonp and ajaxComplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

What I'm trying to achieve is to modify certain page sections with the data pulled from external source (via AJAX jsonp) as soon as a given section loaded or just after the AJAX call is completed (in case the section had loaded before the AJAX was completed and the data became available).

**Example page section (domain1.com)** - there might be more than one section on the page:

```
<div class="mySections" id="section1">          
    Some content
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    sectionRewrite("section1");
</script>
```

**Rest of the code (domain1.com):**

```
myAJAXcomplete = "";
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){ 
    myAJAXcomplete = true;
});

var mySectionData=new Array();
function sectionRewrite(elementID){
        if (myAJAXcomplete == true) {
            $(".mySections#"+elementID).html(mySectionData[elementID]);
        } else {
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
                $(".mySections#"+elementID).html(mySectionData[elementID]);
            });
        }
}

$.ajax({
        data: 'some_data=' + some_data,
        url: "http://domain2.com/somefile.php",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) { 
            for (var key in data) {
                mySectionData[key]=data[key];
            }
        }
});
```

From what I read, it's not possible to have the ajaxComplete working for the AJAX call with the external source (and I got it working for the scenario where the url was on domain1.com) so I'm looking for some alternatives that would work in a similar way: with external data source and quick section overwrite.

I could think of calling the sectionRewrite function every second if the myAJAXcomplete != true but perhaps you can advise something smarter/cleaner?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**
Live code:
http://technow.pl/example-AJAX.php 
This code doesn't overwrite the content of the sections and doesn't call alert() (which I added to the ajaxComplete()). As soon as I change the AJAX url to local one file, everything works fine.

Comment: I haven't heard there was a problem with `ajaxComplete()` and an external source. Do you have a link?

Comment: One of the links i saw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573522/equivalent-to-ajaxsend-and-or-ajaxcomplete-with-jsonp. You can find the live code here: http://technow.pl/example-AJAX.php This code doesn't overwrite the content of the sections and doesn't call alert() (which I added to the ajaxComplete()). As soon as I change the AJAX url to local one file, everything works fine.